# How to use for in loop and query data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query that gets all keys of users in my firebase database. Those keys er saved into an array. I would then like to loop through the array and inside the loop query for the users name. The problem is that it stops when the first name is loaded - the loop does not query through even though there are 1000 keys inside the array?

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) { 
    userIDgotten = emailArray[i];

    console.log(userIDgotten);

    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userIDgotten).once('value').then(function(snapshotUser) {
        const name = snapshotUser.val().name;

        console.log("NAME: " + name);

        allTicketEmailsFromUsers = allTicketEmailsFromUsers + ", " + name;

        console.log(allTicketEmailsFromUsers);
    });
}
```

I get no errors but the loop just stops after the first name is retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

The [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method is asynchronous and returns a Promise.

Since you want to execute several queries with `once()` **in parallel**, you need to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) { 
   userIDgotten = emailArray[i];

   console.log(userIDgotten);

   promises.push(firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userIDgotten).once('value'));

}

Promise.all(promises)
.then(function(results) {
    var allTicketEmailsFromUsers = "";
    results.forEach(function(snapshotUser) {
        const name = snapshotUser.val().name;
        console.log("NAME: " + name);
        allTicketEmailsFromUsers = allTicketEmailsFromUsers + ", " + name;
    });
    console.log(allTicketEmailsFromUsers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `return` in your loop, which stops the loop. 
If you remove that return, it should work the way you expect it to work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) { 
    userIDgotten = emailArray[i];

    console.log(userIDgotten);

    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userIDgotten).once('value').then(function(snapshotUser) {
        const name = snapshotUser.val().name;

        console.log("NAME: " + name);

        allTicketEmailsFromUsers = allTicketEmailsFromUsers + ", " + name;

        console.log(allTicketEmailsFromUsers);
    });
}
```